# Cannot login at login.launchpad.net since the SSL certificate apparently expired?

Tags: launchpad, ssl

This seems to be quite ridiculous but now I can't login at launchpad. Whenever I go to the address login.launchpad.net the browser says that the SSL certificate has expired (expiration date 16 November 2016), and neither Chrome nor Firefox now even allows me to click on "continue" to visit the site. It feels very weird since apparently issues are still being reported and discussed on the site, and a quick Google yielded no result, so I'm not sure what the problem is. Any idea or any temporary workround that I might employ to access the site at this time?

The following is the information shown on the certificate:

```
Ausgestellt für

Allgemeiner Name (CN)   login.launchpad.net
Organisation (O)    Canonical Group Ltd
Organisationseinheit (OU)   <Gehört nicht zum Zertifikat>
Ausgestellt von

Allgemeiner Name (CN)   DigiCert SHA2 Extended Validation Server CA
Organisation (O)    DigiCert Inc
Organisationseinheit (OU)   www.digicert.com
Gültigkeitsdauer

Ausgestellt am  Donnerstag, 12. November 2015 um 01:00:00
Gültig bis  Mittwoch, 16. November 2016 um 13:00:00
Fingerabdrücke

SHA-256-Fingerabdruck   72 A9 26 99 F7 FC 3C F7 DA C2 4F A7 57 B3 7A F8
C2 03 AB 14 EF BC D0 A3 0E 1A 0F A4 9E 6E 09 2D
SHA-1-Fingerabdruck 7C 7A E6 2D C2 E0 D0 DF DF D8 79 12 55 77 FD 26
25 0F 65 D7
```

Comment: Did you clear you caches? I get a valid cert dated 11.06 - 11/30/2017.

Comment: @ubfan1 Well since it happens in both browsers, maybe it's the problem of our university' internet actually. I'll try at a different network later.

Answer (score 0):

Well turns out it seems to be a problem with my university's network. Once I turned on VPN I could connect correctly.